# CLI: Can not fetch members of specific groups

Tags: php, jfactory

on my Joomla-CLI-Script I would like to fetch all user-ids which belong to a specific group.

My script so far:

```
    // $groups = groups that are set in global params
    if(!empty($groups));
    {       
        foreach($groups as $group) :
            $groupmembers = JAccess::getUsersByGroup($group);   

            foreach($groupmembers as $groupmember) :
                $user = JFactory::getUser($groupmember);
                $userarray[] = array(   "email" => $user->email,
                                        "userid" => $user->id); 
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
    }
```

Now I'm getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/web1/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php on line 246

When I edit factory.php and go to line 246, I'm getting this line:

```
elseif (is_string($id) || $instance->id !== $id)
```

So I guess my CLI does not create an instance - but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get the ID's and email's of all users that belong to a specific group, you can do the following:

```
$group_id       = 8;
$usersByGroup   = JAccess::getUsersByGroup($group_id);

foreach ($usersByGroup as $id)
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser($id);
    echo $id;
    echo $user->email;
}
```

Of course, change `8` to the ID of the group you wish to target.

Comment: Hey Lodder,

I thought that I'm doing exactly this? For each group that is given I'm having the foreach-loop which is trying to get the information about that user.

But unfortunately I'm getting the error I was speaking of :-(

Comment: @MyFault - So you're getting the same error even when you use my code instead of yours? Have you ensured you're importing the Joomla API in your CLI script?

Comment: Yes - I'm getting the same error.

I am including the following joomla-libs: http://d.pr/4STE